# Cannot acess previously used Mint on my laptop

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, startup, version

How can I approach to an older version of Linux which is still installed on my laptop but not in use due to some hardware/software problems? I don't see it on the system start-up and I still have some important data stored on the older version, which I cannot access.

Just recently, I installed Linux Mint 19.2 Tina on my laptop, and it works fine, but fixing the older version is a must.

Comment: can you see the partition where the old Mint is on from the new Mint? For example, in File manager or gparted?

Comment: When a new version has been installed, for some time during the startup I was having a multiple choice - to run a new version or to choose an old one. Now I don't see it anymore, system start-up goes with a new version by default, leaving me no choice.

Comment: sure, but can you see the partition where the old Mint is - of course, if you installed a new version and just used the whole disk - then you've wiped the old version - I'd be surprised if you didn't use the whole disk the first time you installed mint, so how would you have installed another operating system without overwriting the old one

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance, I'm not familiar with the programming part of Linux, so someone else performed the installation instead of me. The old Mint isn't overwritten, I could have it seen as an option during the system start-up, but don't see it anymore. Perhaps I failed during the system configuration, but I'm sure it's still there.

Comment: could you give here the output of `sudo parted -l` ?

Comment: I'm really sorry for being a dumbass concerning Linux, here's the output when command is entered as written: parted: neispravna opcija -- „1”
Usage: parted [-hlmsv] [-a<align>] [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]]...] NEISPRAVNA OPCIJA on Croatian language: INCORRECT OPTION

Comment: **`sudo parted -l`**  copy all this text, and I hope you know the password

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot, esp
 2      538MB   214GB  213GB   ext4
 4      214GB   496GB  282GB   ext4
 3      496GB   500GB  4146MB  linux-swap(v1)

This is what I got in return.

Comment: ok, there are two linux partitions: sda2 and sda4. When you open File manager (Nemo?), don't you see "Devices" on the left panel?

Comment: and, please, post here the output of `df /boot`

Comment: Here's the output:  Filesystem       1K-blok     Used Available Use% Montirano
/dev/sda4      270161488 23611248 232757064  10% /

Comment: Then hope that the old Mint is on sda2. Please, read my question before the one with df /boot, it is just possible that File manager shows the other partition.

Comment: The only thing I've found in File Manager are two different icons - vmlinuz and vmlinuz.old. Excuse me, but I'm really dumb for Linux, it's a miracle you're still willing to give me any advices, for which I'm grateful.

Comment: In File manager try to find something like "side pane" - Menu > View and check this or that. Actually, you should update your question with all additional info (the output of parted, df), and add an image of File manager if you like.